# Multiple Rewrite Rules with variables in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use htaccess Rewrite Rules. I need

`http://www.sitename.com/variable/upload.php` 
to map to
`http://sitename.com/upload.php?slug=variable`

`http://www.sitename.com/variable/gallery.php` 
to map to
`http://sitename.com/gallery.php?slug=variable`

`http://www.sitename.com/variable/`
to map to
`http://sitename.com/home.php?slug=variable`

For the third part I have:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+) home.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

But Now `http://www.sitename.com/variable/upload.php` also map to `http://sitename.com/home.php?slug=variable`

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $2?slug=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ home.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

i.e. handle 2 slashes rule before you rewrite to `home.php`